# How can I access variables belonging to one class from an outside class?

Tags: objective-c, properties

I am new to objective c and I guess it has to do with me not understanding pointers or something, but I cannot access a variable outside the class it was declared in.

I know this is a ridiculous question, but I need help.

I have something as simple as an NSString which depending on which tablecell row is selected it grabs the name and stores it in the string. The thing is , I need this string available in another class where the file needs to be loaded using String value. I just get a string is nul or nil whatever error.

I have tried property, synthesize, imports, @class but I guess I dont know what the true meaning of those things are.

Please point me in the right direction.

---

In libraryTableViewController I declare

```
NSString *fileToLoad;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *fileToLoad;
```

in the .m I `@synthesize fileToLoad;` then in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method I `fileToLoad = @"%@", [categories objectAtIndex:row];`

The problem is in another view controller class I want to load from tableViewData plist

```
NSString *myFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileToLoad ofType:@"plist"];
```

but just get nil; ?

Comment: Next time update your question, code in comments is just unreadable ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the code is in another class or instance, you don't have magical access to similarly named properties of other classes/instances - the documentation on [declared properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3218343/how-can-i-access-variables-belonging-to-one-class-from-an-outside-class/3218400#3218400) might help clear misunderstandings.
In your second instance, `fileToLoad` is probably `nil` because it was never initialized there.

You need to have a reference to the instance you want to have the value from and retrieve the property value:

```
NSString *myFileToLoad = myTableViewController.fileToLoad;
```

Depending on your architecture there might also be other/better solutions.

Comment: If I declare a myTableViewController in the class and then try use it in another I just get the same error.

Comment: Nah, I meant, I get the undeclared error for the myViewController like I did with the myFileToLoad.

Comment: @alj, the idea was: Add e.g. a property `myTableViewController` for the second class and set its value to the instance of the first from somewhere where it is known.

Answer (score 3):

From the sounds of it, you need to read up on Object Oriented Programming. Apple have some guides on OOP and how it is implemented in Objective-C here:

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/oop_objc/articles/oooop.html

Comment: Thanks, I know OOP from Java. Just stuck on some obj-c parts. I will read it thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just a couple of points about your code:

1. You've declared an NSString variable to a property using `retain` for memory management. The correct memory management model for class clusters that have mutable/immutable types is `copy`
2. Even though you've declared `fileToLoad` as a property, you're setting it directly in the `didSelectRowAtIndex` method, which bypasses the memory management and any KVO/KVC notifications that changing the property may generate. You should change the property value using `self.fileToLoad` except in initialisation or tear down methods.

Comment: Thanks. but please, I am driving insane. How would you grab the selected tablecell.text and use that text in another class to load the plist with that name? I still cant get mine to work.